# How to exclud thousands of page in Nuxt middlware

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware

I wrote below in nuxt.config.js

```
// nuxt.config.js

router: {
    middleware: ['authenticated']
  },
```

By doing this, authenticated.js middleware is applied to all pages.

I write below for describing pages to being excluded in authenticated.js.

```
// authenticated.js

if(['signup','signin'].includes(route.name)){
    return;
  }
```

But if I have thousands of pages to being excluded, it would be difficult to use this way.

So What would you recommend for alternatives?

Thank yor for reading my question.

Comment: for pages which dont require authenticated, simply don't include the middleware, so move it out of nuxt.config and into the page

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why it would be difficult. Programmatically get all the pages to exclude or use a regex for example.